Find events that are part of a timespan cluster of size N
I have a table of events like the following:
id | time  | location | user
1  | 08:55 | x        | A
2  | 08:57 | x        | B
3  | 08:58 | y        | C
4  | 08:59 | x        | A
5  | 09:01 | x        | C
6  | 09:01 | x        | D
7  | 09:04 | x        | B
8  | 09:08 | x        | C
9  | 09:12 | x        | D

I want to find all event IDs where N or more distinct users have produced an event at the same location within 5 minutes. For N=3, this would be IDs 2, 4, 5, 6, 7; for N=4, it is event IDs 2, 4, 5, 6. The exact definition of the timespan doesn't matter much, it could be 4.999 or 5.0001 minutes as well.
SQL to construct the table:
CREATE TABLE event (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    time time(0),
    location char,
    usr char
);
INSERT INTO event (time, location, usr) VALUES
    ('08:55', 'x', 'A'),
    ('08:57', 'x', 'B'),
    ('08:58', 'y', 'C'),
    ('08:59', 'x', 'A'),
    ('09:01', 'x', 'C'),
    ('09:01', 'x', 'D'),
    ('09:04', 'x', 'B'),
    ('09:08', 'x', 'C'),
    ('09:12', 'x', 'D');

What I have so far is this query, which produces pairs of (first event in cluster, other event in cluster), but it's incorrect - it only checks that following events in the cluster have a different user than the first event, but not that they're distinct amongst each other:
SELECT id, following_id
FROM  (
    SELECT
        event.id,
        following_event.id AS following_id,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY event.id) AS num_following
    FROM event
    INNER JOIN event AS following_event USING (location)
    WHERE
        following_event.usr != event.usr
        AND following_event.time >= event.time
        AND following_event.time < event.time + '00:05:00'
)
WHERE num_following >= 2;

 id | following_id
----+--------------
  2 |            6
  2 |            4
  2 |            5
  4 |            5
  4 |            6
  5 |            7
  5 |            6
  6 |            7
  6 |            5

I could porbbaly filter this down to distinct following_ids, then massage it until it's deduplicated to just 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, but it feels like there might be a better approach entirely.

#2 and #7 are not within 5 minutes. Why still put them in the same cluster?

Please define "within 5 minutes" exactly. And disclose your version of Postgres.

@Bergi it's not about being "in the same cluster", but being in any such cluster. 7 is in a cluster with 5 and 6.

@Lamdba If you want to get the clusters [2, 4, 5, 6] and [5, 6, 7] separately, your approach seems to be working fine. If you want to get [2, 4, 5, 6, 7] as a single response, you'll have to expand on your definition of "cluster"/"within 5 minutes".

For any arbitrary timespan of 5 minutes (±epsilon), if there are N or more events at the same location by distinct users within this timespan, those events match the condition. The IDs for all events that match the condition in any timespan should be returned.

The more crucial part to define about "within 5 minutes" is the "within". It's unclear how lower and upper bound of the timespan are defined exactly. Like: "for each row, between 5 min earlier, exclusive, and time of the current row, inclusive"?

As already added in the post, I don't really care about the exact precise definition of "within", hence also the "± epsilon". Take any period of time where the end is 5 minutes (or 4 minutes 59 seconds, or 5 minutes 1 second) after the start, that's the timespan to count events in.

You can adjust the frame definition of window functions to fit your time window. Unfortunately, neither DISTINCT nor ORDER BY are allowed in window functions. One workaround is to collect all usr in an array, and count distinct elements in a second step:
SELECT id, all_usr, c.ct_dist
FROM   (
   SELECT id
        , array_agg(usr) OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY time
                               RANGE BETWEEN '4:59.999999 min' PRECEDING
                                         AND '4:59.999999 min' FOLLOWING) AS all_usr
   FROM   event e
   ) sub
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT u) AS ct_dist FROM unnest(all_usr) u
   ) c ON ct_dist >= 4;

Update: that's only a super-set of your desired solution, as I understand it now. (See comments.)
If you can operate with integer (int4) values, tools from the additional module intarray should make this faster:
SELECT id, all_usr, cardinality(uniq(sort(all_usr))) AS ct_dist
FROM   (
   SELECT id
        , array_agg(ascii(usr)) OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY time
                                RANGE BETWEEN '4:59.999999 min' PRECEDING
                                          AND '4:59.999999 min' FOLLOWING) AS all_usr
   FROM   event e
   ) sub
WHERE  cardinality(uniq(sort(all_usr))) >= 4;

fiddle
I extract the ASCII value from each letter in the column usr to get integer values. In real life you should have usr_id int to begin with.
Related:

Storing and comparing unique combinations

I chose the odd interval '4:59.999999 min' since you seem to want to exclude bound of the time range.

Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be correct - with the added test data I've just put in the original post, it also catches events that are preceded and followed by another by five minutes each, but that's not a cluster of three, just two overlapping clusters of two.

Still not sure how lower and upper bound of the timespan are defined exactly. While being at it, I removed the ascii conversion from query 1, where it's not needed.

@Lamdba: I see. You want a frame within the given maximum interval and dynamic upper and lower bounds that includes the current row and at least 3 distinct users. That's not covered by available options for window frames. My query uses a static frame, so the result is a superset of qualifying rows. (Might be of some use already.) Narrowing it down really needs a procedural algorithm. I can envision a PL/pgSQL function with moving frames. But that's currently beyond the scope of answering a question for me. Good luck.
